# Структура папок и классов в проекте C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, классы

Разросся проект C# (visual studio) до пары десятков файлов cs.
Хочется разложить их по папкам (файлы классов .cs)
Как это сделать?
Если можно то объясните подробнее, или дайте ссылку на правильную статью.

Из того что я нагуглил, одни ответы говорят что ничего не нужно делать, просто разложить по папкам, а другие пишут жуткие инструкции по переносу. Кому верить?

Comment: А попробовать религия не позволяет? Вы ведь программист и должны сами пробовать что-то новое. Так что вам мешает создать класс и поместить его в другую директорию? Если все устраивает, то так и оставляйте, если нет, то поменяйте еще и `namespace` класса.

Comment: А какой у вас тип приложения? Консольное? Или Windows Forms? В шаблонах веб-проектов (с некот. исключениями) уже начальная структура папок создается сразу.

Comment: @Bulson Приложение консольное. И конкретно это с одним namespace-ом.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я то попробовал. Приложение работает. Но закралось сомнение.  
Вот думаю в будущем начнутся проблемы из-за этого, а я даже не буду знать что проблемы связаны с моими папками.

Comment: `...а я даже не буду знать что проблемы связаны с моими папками` - папки для вас, а `namespace`ы для компилятора.

Comment: @BeginnerCoderCS Проблемы могут быть в именах и `namespace` их делайте с умом, а вот папки, это всего лишь удобное расположение файлов для вас, не более.

Answer (score 1):

Структура должна быть максимально простой и понятной не только вам, но и остальным. Один из возможных вариантов, это от файлов, которые хранят высокоуровневые методы, классы, и т.д. до низших. 
К примеру:

```
// Основные классы, которые будут дальше использоваться в проекте,
// реализующие некие интерфейсы.
Core -> (Interfaces) & (Classes)

// Тут будем хранить классы, которые используют уже основные классы,
// методы и т.д.
Сlasses -> { ... ... ...}

// Тут будем хранить кастомные контролы,
// которые будут реализовываться в проекте.
Controls -> { ... ... ...}

// Тут будем хранить формы, которые уже будут использовать (например)
// наши контролы, классы, методы, и т.д.
Forms -> { ... ... ...}

// Тут будем хранить какие-то стили, современные палитры цветов,
// которые мы хотим использовать в проекте.
Styles -> { ... ... ...}

// Тут будем хранить остальной полезный "хлам",
// который уже некуда приткнуть.
Other -> { ... ... ...}
```

Подключать наши расфасованные классы, стили и т.д. будем так:

```
using (namespace проекта).Core.Classes;
using (namespace проекта).Classes;
```

... и т.д.

Вообще можете сами использовать любую структуру, какую только захотите, но постарайтесь сделать так, чтоб навигация по папкам была интуитивно понятной и логичной.

P.S. Структурировать файлы необходимо начинать с самого начала разработки проекта, иначе могут возникнуть неприятные проблемы, связанные с названиями проектов, бесконечными перемещениями файлов из папки в папку - всё это до добра не доведёт.

Comment: `...понятной не только вам, но и остальным` - остальных может и не быть 

Comment: ну, если человек собирается, допустим, выложить свой проект на GitHub, то правильная структура проекта облегчит разбор кода, я же прав?)

Comment: правы, я просто пошутил.

Comment: @Bulson, да я понял)

Comment: И вот опять 2 мнения.  
Первое: папки только для программиста  
Второе: правильная структура файлов using (namespace проекта).Core.Classes;  
   
Я не говорю  что кто-то не прав, но хотелось бы с этим разобраться раз и навсегда.   
  
С web (html, css) всё понятно, там папка это в прямом смысле папка. А вот с кодом непонятки (

Comment: @BeginnerCoderCS Мнение одно, вы просто его почему то делите на 2. В коде нет папок, есть `namespace`, благодаря которым в коде разделяют классы по своим логическим группам. Например класс `File` - у него логический `namespace System.IO`. Папки же в самом проекте на код совершенно не влияют, они созданы для удобства программистов, что бы не в одной директории было 1000 классов, а разделено по разным директориям. Файл может быть где угодно, в коде это нечего не изменит.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ что папки только для программистов это хорошо.  
Объясните как работает вот это using (namespace проекта).Core.Classes;
using (namespace проекта).Classes;

Comment: @BeginnerCoderCS Когда вы создаете новый файл `.cs`, вы получаете класс, который имеет в самом начале `using...`, дальше идет `namespace SomeNameSpace { ... }` и уже внутри размещается класс. То есть выше описанный мною класс `File` имеет в начале `namespace System.IO { ... }`. Тем самым вы можете написать `System.IO.File` (сразу с namespace), либо дополнить `using` сверху, написав `using System.IO` и уже в коде писать сразу название класса. Такой подход позволяет структурировать все, размещая логически по своим местам, а также использовать одинаковые имена, поместив их в разные `namespace`.

Comment: @BeginnerCoderCS, извини конечно, но что непонятного? Ты подключаешь директорию, в которой хранятся какие-то методы, которые используются/будешь использовать в проекте. Дословно using (с анг.) обозначает: с помощью, с использованием, при помощи. Если есть желание, можешь на msdn почитать о ключевых словах, используемых для пространств имён -> [Ключевые слова C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/).